# C++ time (and not date) period

Tags: c++

I want to check if the current time (in C++) is between a time range.

I want to construct the time range from a tuple ("12:00", "17:30"), ie (string, string) and check if the time now() is between.

Any good way to do this? I don't want to check dates, ie I don't care if the day is Monday or the month is October. I care only for times.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: as I said I haven't find any easy way to create a time period using standard library. Of course this can be done, however I was asking if there is a canonical way to resolve this, as it is a very common problem.

Comment: _"as I said I haven't find any easy way to create a time period using standard library"_ That doesn't make the question _"Any good library to do this without the need to reinvent the wheel?"_ on-topic.

Comment: Okay, to make the question more acceptable, I have modified it a little so that it asks for a *way* to do this rather than an off-site resource. That doesn't, of course, mean people can't *answer* with an off-site resource :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo That's probably why you're carrying that nick ;-)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the strings in the tuple can be forced to be `HH:MM`, you can use simple string comparison<sup>(a)</sup>.

The following complete program shows how to get the current time as a string:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

std::string getNowHhMm() {
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *local = localtime(&now);
    char buff[sizeof("hh:mm")];
    strftime(buff, sizeof(buff), "%H:%M", local);
    return buff;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << getNowHhMm() << std::endl;
}
```

Using that function, you can also provide one to see if it's a given range:

```
bool isBetween(
    const std::string &now,
    const std::string &lo,
    const std::string &hi
) {
    return (now >= lo) && (now <= hi);
}
```

and call it with:

```
if (isBetween(getNowHhMm(), lowestTime, highestTime))
    std::cout << "It's in the range.\n';
```

And, for efficiency, remember to store the return value from `getNowHhMm()` if you're going to be checking more than one range:

```
std::string now = getNowHhMm();

if (isBetween(now, "00:00", "05:59"))
    std::cout << "It's too early to get up.\n";
else if (isBetween(now, "06:00", "07:59"))
    std::cout << "Time to rise.\n";
else if (isBetween(now, "08:00", "11:59"))
    std::cout << "Get out of bed, ya lazy slob.\n";
else
    std::cout << "Sleep in, you're probably already fired.\n";
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Yes, it's re-inventing the wheel but, given how simple this wheel is, I'd suggest it's a good solution.

Comment: Do we need the strNow?

Comment: @cateof If you don't want to replicate the behavior with `strcmp()`, yes.

Comment: @cateof, as 42 says, the alternative is something like `if ((strcmp(buff, lowestTime) >= 0) && (strcmp(buff, highestTime) <= 0)) ...` - I consider that rather ugly in C++.

Comment: @paxdiablo so we need to ensure that time will be 08:07??? do we need leading zeros in all cases?

Comment: @cateof: yes: `09:58, 09:59, 10:00, 10:01` (just to clarify you don't need leading zeros from 10am onward). Without the `HH:MM` format, you'll need more complex checking logic.

Answer (score 1):

If your times are always `hh:mm`, memcmp does it. If your times are of the form `h:mm` or `hh:mm`, you can use `(cmp = strlen(x) - strlen(y)) ? cmp : strcmp(x, y)`.